# Atualizar form secundário sem mudar o foco do primario

Tags: delphi, eventos

Eu desenvolvi um programa em Delhi que tem dois *forms*, um com uma *grid* e outro com um mapa, o funcionamento é simples: ao se clicar no grid a posição do veiculo é atualizada no mapa, o problema é que toda vez que eu chamo a *procedure* no formulário do mapa para atualizar a posição eu perco o foco do form que contem o *grid*, e mesmo que eu jogue o foco de volta fica feio as janelas mudando de cores devido a perca do foco.

Como eu posso atualizar os dados da janela secundária sem que passar o foco para ela?

Comment: O fato de chamar um método de um form não implica na passagem do foco para ele, então imagino que você esteja disparando alguma operação que transfira o foco. De que forma você comanda a atualização da janela secundária?

Comment: Não há informações suficientes para resolver seu problema. Queira postar o código de um programa simples com o problema.

Comment: Graças as dicas de todos vocês eu descobri que um dos compomentes que eu estou usando pede pelo foco quando chamado, usando a dica do Raphael Zimermann eu estou setando a visibilidade para falso, chamando o compomente e setando para verdadeiro. O que nesse caso não tem problema porque a função desenha na tela e o que ela faz eh apagar de um ponto e criar em outro.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Tente isso:

```pascal
procedure BotãoFormGridClick(Sender: TObject);
begin

   FormulárioMapa.Visible := False; // Oculta o form, fazendo com que qualquer 
                                   // foco não seja executado
   FormulárioMapa.ProcedimentoMapa(); // Executa seu procediemnto
   FormulárioMapa.Visible := True; // Não usar um 'Show()'. Com o visible, 
                                   // ele volta a aparecer sem executar um foco

end;
```

Answer (score 1):

Conforme [uma resposta](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2423234/make-a-form-not-focusable-in-c-sharp) no stackoverflow.com, você consegue fazer uma janela não ter o foco ativado nele sobreescrevendo a função CreateParams e em C# fica assim:

```cs
private const int WS_EX_NOACTIVATE = 0x08000000;
protected override CreateParams CreateParams
{
    get
    {
        CreateParams createParams = base.CreateParams;
        createParams.ExStyle = WS_EX_NOACTIVATE;
        return createParams;
    }
}
```

Já [neste artigo](http://delphi.about.com/od/formsdialogs/l/aa073101a.htm) do delphi.about.com, temos que esta função pode ser sobre escrita em Delphi da seguinte maneira:
1º

```pascal
private
procedure CreateParams
 (var Params: TCreateParams); override;
```

2º

```pascal
procedure TForm.CreateParams(var Params: TCreateParams);
begin
inherited CreateParams(Params);

{ -- seu código aqui -- }

end;
```

Grandes são as chances de que se você conseguir reproduzir a função mostrada em C# no Delphi você obterá o mesmo resultado pela alteração.

Answer (score -1):

Você pode usar esta implementação (https://bitbucket.org/marciomartins/notificationservice). Basicamente você assina uma mensagem e cada vez que ela ocorrer, dispara uma ação e pode até enviar um objeto.
Se tiver dificuldades de usar avise que posto um exemplo.

Comment: Evite fazer com que toda a resposta dependa de um link externo. Normalmente as respostas contém um texto explicativo, um trecho de código exemplo (algo que resolva o questionamento principal da pergunta) e um link de referencia(um conteúdo mais extenso onde poderia encontrar mais detalhes a respeito da solução).
Assim se um dia o link ficar fora do ar ainda resta o conteúdo do SO para consulta.